# Is there a way to whitelist mailto: links on iOS phonegap?

Tags: cordova, ios8

I am trying to restrict mailto: on iOS Phonegap so that I can create an app where the user cannot be redirected to the mail client. I made the necessary changes in the /config.xml but still all the mailto: calls open the default mail client. Is there any way to restrict it in config.xml? I could not find sufficient documents for this on phonegap website.

Comment: What you want is to reconfigure the way the URL is dispatched. This might be doable in JavaScript or by iOS configuration, but it's not the responsibility of PhoneGap.

Comment: Show your config.xml

Comment: which cordova version do you use?